# request.GET.get(), How it works in django?

Tags: python, django

```
removepunct = request.GET.get('removepunc','off')
```

This is my django template code

```
<form action='/analyze' method='get'>
        <textarea name='text' style="margin: 0px; width: 1567px; height: 221px;"></textarea>
        <button type='submit'>Analyze Text</button><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="removepunc">Remove Punctutations 
        <input type="checkbox" name="fullcapitalize">Full Capitalize<br>

    </form>
```

Actually,I am new to django and want to know about request.GET.get(). Actually if checkbox is not checked then it returns "off" the second parameter and if its "on" returns on.
I know GET contains GET variable and .get() used for dictionary for getting values of keys but question is "how the second arquement is selected if checkbox is off" because .get() takes keys as a arguements?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument is returned in case the key provided in the first argument is not found in the dictionary on which the `.get()` method is applied. If it is not provided and the first argument is not found in the dictionary, `.get()` returns `None` instead.